# How to erase part of UIImageView with finger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, cgcontext

Basically I just want to make an **eraser** just like in `Paint`. I want to erase parts of a `UIImageView` just with my finger. I use the following code, however, it erases only with small strokes, while I want it to erase until I pull my finger off:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:bg];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    CGFloat brushSize = 35;

    CGColorRef strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:bg];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bg.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context2 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [bg.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, bg.frame.size.width, bg.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(context2, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context2, brushSize);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context2, strokeColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context2, kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextBeginPath(context2);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context2, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context2, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context2);
    bg.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastTouch = currentTouch;

}
```

How should I change my code?

Comment: See here for an example of drawing to a `UIView` which is backed/buffered by a `UIImage`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835952/sketch-on-uiview-within-uiscrollview/40836955#40836955  You can modify it to set stroke colour and size to whatever you want..